# python self-less

Tags: python, class, self

this works in the desired way:

```
class d:
    def __init__(self,arg):
        self.a = arg
    def p(self):
        print "a= ",self.a

x = d(1)
y = d(2)
x.p()
y.p()
```

yielding

```
a=  1
a=  2
```

i've tried eliminating the "self"s and using a global statement in `__init__`

```
class d:
    def __init__(self,arg):
        global a
        a = arg
    def p(self):
        print "a= ",a

x = d(1)
y = d(2)
x.p()
y.p()
```

yielding, undesirably:

```
a=  2
a=  2
```

is there a way to write it without having to use "self"?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to make my code more readable.

Comment: That would make it a) less pythonic and b) broken.

Comment: *Of course* `global a` leads to `a` being shared by all instances. That's pretty much the definition of a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python methods are just functions that are bound to the class or instance of a class. The only difference is that a method (aka bound function) expects the instance object as the first argument.  Additionally when you invoke a method from an instance, it automatically passes the instance as the first argument. So by defining `self` in a method, you're telling it the namespace to work with.

This way when you specify `self.a` the method knows you're modifying the instance variable `a` that is part of the instance namespace.

Python scoping works from the inside out, so each function (or method) has its own namespace.  If you create a variable `a` locally from within the method `p` (these names suck BTW), it is distinct from that of `self.a`.  Example using your code:

```
class d:
    def __init__(self,arg):
        self.a = arg
    def p(self):
        a = self.a - 99
        print "my a= ", a
        print "instance a= ",self.a


x = d(1)
y = d(2)
x.p()
y.p()
```

Which yields:

```
my a=  -98
instance a=  1
my a=  -97
instance a=  2
```

Lastly, you don't have to call the first variable `self`.  You could call it whatever you want, although you really shouldn't. It's convention to define and reference `self` from within methods, so if you care at all about other people reading your code without wanting to kill you, stick to the convention!

Further reading:

- [Python Classes tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Nice explanation, misleading terminology in the beginning though: What we call a *bound* method already has the instance (as implicit first argument), an *unbound* method (in Python 2, it has its own type; in Python 3, it's just a plain function but the concept still exists) still needs the instance (as explicit first argument).

Comment: this has been my first question posted.  i see the question is rated as -1, but i am not sure why.  is it because the question is inappropriate for SO? or is poorly presented? or because my replies were out of format?

Comment: @delnan: You're not entirely correct.  If you define a naked function that takes `self` as its first argument, and then assign it to the class object, any instances of that class will inherit that function as a bound method.  In this case all you did was create a function, attached it to a class, and it became a method. However, you are right in that the actual `type` of `function` changes to that of `instancemethod`.

Comment: @mike: Someone didn't like your question and downvoted it. It's generally better to be more descriptive in the original question than to followup in comments. :)

Comment: How does does that conflict with anything I said?

Comment: Imho the best explanation of the mysterious 'self'  for beginners. +1

Answer (score 6):

"self" is the way how Python works. So the answer is: No! If you want to cut hair: You don't have to use "self". Any other name will do also. ;-)

Comment: ok ... so i just ought to get use to having a lot of "self"s in my code?

Comment: @mike: Yes, full stop, new paragraph. You're pretty much asking the Python equivalent to "how can I avoid the preprocessor in C and C++".

Comment: "a lot" depends on your point of view, but obviously more than in other languages. Having way too much of them might be a hint that there's a problem with your code.

Comment: "Explicit is better than Implicit"

Comment: Look on the bright side, you won't be tempted to prepend `m_` to your member variables just to clarify the namespaces being accessed inside a method :)

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the self's, you end up having only one variable called `a` that will be shared not only amongst all your `d` objects but also in your entire execution environment.
You can't just eliminate the self's for this reason.

Comment: ok, i see now that the the global statement raises the variable to the execution level